# ERROR The specified file 'helidon-quickstart-se.jar' not exists in helidon se project

Tags: java, maven, microservices, maven-archetype, helidon

I am very new to Helidon and have been trying to generate a Helidon project using the quickstart archetype, but it seems to be not working at all for me. can you please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

**what I have tried is as follows:
mvn -U archetype:generate "-DinteractiveMode=false" "-DarchetypeGroupId=io.helidon.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=helidon-quickstart-se" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.3.0" "-DgroupId=io.helidon.examples" "-DartifactId=helidon-quickstart-se" "-Dpackage=io.helidon.examples.quickstart.se" "-DgeneratePom=true"**

and the error that I am getting is as follows:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igUuc.png)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the 1.3.0 version of helidon-quickstart-se jar was not present in my central repository, so I had to install the particular jar in my central repository using the command:
**mvn install:install-file -Dfile=helidon-quickstart-se.jar -DgroupId=io.helidon.archetypes -DartifactId=helidon-quickstart-se -Dversion=1.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar**

Then it worked for me.
Hope this helps someone who is stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Just a quick note to say that Helidon is at version 2.0.1.